# CSS Menu system not working in IOS 8

Tags: ios, css, menu, touch, submenu

I implemented this css dropdown menu system a few years ago and I am just realizing now that it does not work on my iPhone, yet it works fine on my bosses android phone.  I was under the impression that since IOS5, i-devices do register a touch event as a hover automatically but I guess I was wrong.
The structure of this menu is a little weird in that the main tabs (other than Home and Contact) are not meant to take the user anywhere, only the submenu items actually go to another page.  I have a feeling this is where the issue may lie, but I can't figure it out.

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/7ndkg6su/3/).

The `:hover` is on `<li>` to cause the dropdown.  Maybe this is the issue? or maybe its the way my boss coded the button so it would look like a link but not do anything on a click:

```
<li id="aboutus" class="blogbutton"><a><span>About Us</span></a>
```

I tried removing the anchor tags and the whole button goes away.  I removed the span tags and the original problem still remains.

Is there a fix without having to rewrite the whole menu system?

Comment: You may want to go the route of adding a toggle class.  So when they click it gets an "open" class added to it.  Not the most beautiful solution but should help with all those mobile browsers that don't make life easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `onclick="return True;"` attribute to the base menu that triggers the drop-down. Safari will trigger the hover attributes, but only if it thinks that the element does something when it's tapped, and for a static element like a `li`, this is the easiest way to achieve that.